# function pdf_create doesn't work using DOMPDF

Tags: php, email-attachments, dompdf

**function pdf_create doesn't work using DOMPDF** Doesn't work!!

I have a project that I am working on that calls the child page via ID. and I would like that Page to be convert to PDF and send it to an email.

I have done some search and I have come to a sort of working clause. But I can't still get it right. Anyone help will be appreciated.

Here is my page url: `file_html?sts=4590`

Here is my DomPDF that will convert to PDF:

```
require("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
function pdf_create($html, $filename, $paper, $orientation, $stream=TRUE){
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_paper($paper, $orientation);
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
}
$filename = 'new_jobcard';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = file_get_contents(curPageName());
pdf_create($html, $filename, 'A4', 'portrait');
```

**Is it possible to convert a child link page like `file_html?sts=4596` to PDF and Save it to the server?**

Comment: You instantiate dompdf inside *and* outside your `pdf_create()` function, doesn't look like you need the outside instance.

Comment: You don't indicate what `curPageName()` does. Presumably it uses the value in the sts variable to render the HTML document?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "Doesn't work!!". Do you get any errors or warnings? Does anything happen at all?

Comment: Yes, It's does save but the html table format is well present!  I used this structure. Now it can save to the server but the html is unformat. `require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$files = glob("dompdf/include/*.php");
$paper= "letter";
$orientation= "portrait";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
 $dompdf->set_paper($paper, $orientation);
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents('new_jobcard.pdf', $output);` **Any Idea**? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with the code in your comment (you should edit your post if you try something new). But let's forget all that for now. You're loading your document via `$dompdf->load_html()`. That means any external file references that do not include a protocol and domain (e.g. css/styles.css or /css/styles.css) will be relative to the executing script on the local file system. So make sure those paths make sense from that file. Or just use a full URI (e.g. http://example.com/css/styles.css).

Comment: Sorry, the full URI example should be `http://example.com/css/styles.css` (with the protocol).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that! I Appreciate it!